# Spring bean initialize maps using external property file

Tags: java, spring

I have a class which has a Map as its member variable. Something like this -

```
public Clas Engine{
  private Map<String,List<String>> filesByKey;

  public void setFilesByKey(Map<String,List<String>> map) {
    this.filesByKey = map;
   }
   public Map<String,List<String>> getFilesByKey() {
    return filesByKey;
   }
}
```

User can specify any number of keys in the map and its not predefined concept. They can basically group any number of files into one key and provider the map Value.

I was using PropertyOverrideConfigurer and in the properties file, I was trying to do something like this -

```
engine.filesByKey[key1][0]=file1
engine.filesByKey[key1][1]=file2
engine.filesByKey[key2][0]=anotherfile1
engine.filesByKey[key2][1]=anotherfile2
```

Now this is not working because the the List value corresponding to key1 or key2 is null to being with. So Spring Bean creation fails with the message that it can not set value to a property which is NULL.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [LazyMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LazyMap.html) & [LazyList](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/list/LazyList.html) from commons collections to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your filesByKey variable with [DefaultedMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/DefaultedMap.html) from commons collections. It can return default value instead of null if map doesn't contain required key.